# Sending mail with through python with roundcube

Tags: python, smtp, webmail

Am trying to send mail with `python` using my `rouncube webmail` but when i run it outputs this error `TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond`

I checked in my mail and my port is `"290"` which have provided but when i run the function the mail doesn't send. I know how to send with `gmail` by `turning on less secure app access` but don't know how to work around to send with my `webmail`.

I need your suggestion to work around it.

```
from smtplib import SMTP_SSL as SMTP
import logging, logging.handlers, sys
from email.mime.text import MIMEText



def send_message():
    text = '''
            Hello,

            Trying to send mail from my webmail in python 3. 

            Sincerely,

            My name
            '''

    message = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
    message['Subject'] = "Email Subject"
    my_email = 'joe@mycompany.com'

    # Email that you want to send a message
    message['To'] = my_email

    # You need to change here, depending on the email that you use.
    # For example, Gmail and Yahoo have different smtp. You need to know what it is.
    connection = SMTP('smtp.roundcube.com', 290)
    connection.set_debuglevel(True)

    # Attention: You can't put for example: 'your_address@email.com'.
    #            You need to put only the address. In this case, 'your_address'.
    connection.login('fred.kings', 'fredsw321a')

    try:
        # sendemail(<from address>, <to address>, <message>)
        connection.sendmail(my_email, my_email, message.as_string())
    finally:
        connection.close()



send_message()
```

Comment: Sounds like you  have the in corect SMTP server. I would double  check that smtp.roundcube.com and 290 are the server and port

Comment: When i do this `connection = SMTP('smtp.mycompany.com', 290)` the i still get same error.

Comment: @DaImTo have find any answer with regards to the question.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using:

- Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS.
- Python 3.7.4
- Jupyter-Notebook 6.0.1
- Anaconda 1.7.2

I can successfully send an email through Python with Roundcube, executing the following script in a jupyter-notebook cell:

```py
import smtplib

email = "myemail@mycompany.com"
password = "mypassword"
to = ["destination@dest.com"]

with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('mail.mycompany.com', 465) as smtp:

    smtp.login(email, password)

    subject = "testing mail sending"
    body = "the mail itself"

    msg = "Subject: {}\n\n{}".format(subject, body)

    smtp.sendmail(email, to, msg)
```

I found this information as follows (so you can find yours):

- Log into you company email.
- Look for the following image and click on it (Webmail Home).

[image]

- You'll see something like the following:

[image]

- Scroll down, looking for the following image and click on it (Configure Mail...).

[image]

- Look for the info at mail server section.

[image]

If there are using port 465 (such as in my case) it means that you want to use smtplib.SMTP_SSL instead of smtplib.SMTP.

**NOTE:** The previous worked for me from my personal computer, however, when I tried to use the same code, from my "virtual machine" at office, it **does not** work, which makes me think that there is a system limitation, and that the problem is not code-related.

Hope it helps, regards.

Comment: It really helped. The simplicity is score 10/10.